# Wrong media files url on WordPress site

Tags: wordpress

I have met a problem on WordPress site:
None images uploaded as media files are showing. I see they have wrong url like this

```
<a class="thumbLink" href="http:///wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Joseph-Angharad-11.7.2014-271.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]" title=""><i class="icon-search"></i></a>
```

I've tried to upload new media files and they get similar url and don't displayed.
In the database it seems ok. I don't see such url in it. 
Have you met such a problem? Where to look resolving?

As far as I know it happened before removing a plugin (which was inactive).

I get images via the following code:

```
// instantiate the controller
if (!function_exists("peTheme")) {
    $peThemeClassName = apply_filters('pe_theme_controller_classname','PeTheme'.PE_THEME_NAME);

    PeGlobal::$controller =& new $peThemeClassName();

    function &peTheme() {
        return PeGlobal::$controller;
    }

    peTheme()->boot();

}

<?php $t =& peTheme(); ?>

<section class="thumbImage">
    <img src="<?php echo $t->image->resizedImgUrl($content->get_origImage(),350,0); ?>" alt="" class="fullwidth">
    <div class="thumbTextWrap">
        <div class="thumbText">
            <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><h3 class="sectionTitle"><?php $content->title(); ?></h3></a>
    <?php 
        $text = get_the_excerpt();
            if (strlen($text) > 40)
            $text = substr($text, 0, 40) . '...';

            echo '<p>' . $text . '</p>';
    ?>

    <?php while ($slide =& $slider->next()): ?>

    <?php $img = $slide->img; ?>
    <?php
        if ( $first ) { 
    ?>
    <a class="thumbLink" href="<?php echo $img; ?>" rel="prettyPhoto['<?php $content->slug(); ?>']" title=""><i class="icon-search"></i></a>
    <?php
        $first = false;
        } else {
    ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $img; ?>" rel="prettyPhoto['<?php $content->slug(); ?>']" title=""></a>
    <?php
        }

    <?php endwhile; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
 </section>
```

Comment: what happens if you `var_dump(site_url());`. The site_url is missing in the `href` attribute. Show the code of how you get the image.

Comment: I updated question, please take a look

Comment: You're missing something in that code...what's `$t`? Where does `$t->image->resizedImgUrl` come from?

Comment: @mevius I added something I missed but this code separated to several files and I not strong in PHP so if I miss something else please tell me and I'll try to find it.

Answer (score 1):

It quite silly of me but I didn't disable plugins to check.
The problem was in a Parallelize plugin. It has been disabled and from now media files have right url.

Comment: That plugin sadly hasn't been updated in so long. It doesn't work anymore!

Answer (score 0):

This post may be a little outdated, but I had a similar recent issue so in case it proves useful to anyone:

To start, I had previously changed the Wordpress upload directory by adding the following to the end of wp-config.php

```
define( 'UPLOADS', ''.'files' );
```

So all my files are saved in `domain.com/files/` After upgrading to Wordpress 4.5, all media files had very wrong url, (with something crazy like .../wp-content/uploads/rootuser/public_html/wp-content/uploads...) I tried reinstalling Wordpress, changing the directory again, disabling plugins, then I found a few posts about the [Search & Replace](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-and-replace/) working for some, but still no luck.

Then I found this plugin, [Upload Url and Path Enabler](https://wordpress.org/plugins/upload-url-path-enabler/) and used the following settings that suited my situation:

Store Files: `files`

Full File URL: `http://www.domain.com/files`

And presto! All media URLs magically updated and all is working again!